# Attach the points of one path to the location of another path

Tags: bezier-curves

Basically, I want to model a ship hull, but rather than modeling it by hand, I would like to use paths. One way to do that would be to create two sets of paths, where the points of the one set (which would be the ribs) are constrained in two axes by the second set (would run the length of the ship).

If there are other ways to parametrically model a hull (as opposed to using brushes), those answers are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively no, as far as I know. That sounds like the realm of NURBS based modelling, which is a stranger in Blender lands.

Maybe you should look into ACIS solid based modelling software, or NURBS surfaces modelling tools instead.

Otherwise if you want to stick with Blender maybe look into parametric modelling addons like [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes), or [Sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) which allow parametric modelling with a node based workflow.

If you want something simpler [BSurfaces](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5) may also be worth a shot. It allows creating surfaces between bounding curve objects, like lofting, tabbed surfaces or ruled surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i made generative ship some time ago for one person.
You model splines, use sverchok  object in node, interpolation, uvconnect node, also vis draw node to show polygons and vertices.
but than you can make join mesh node and use this manifold object with bisect node to create frame inside.
gist for import in sverchok:
https://gist.github.com/7d06b7a30442ffc1da403e0c56952ef1
[image]
Use two curves for object in node (GET button) that have origin in 0,0,0 point.

Version 2 with link to blend file.
[image]
https://yadi.sk/d/HtE5e4033LfVjw